# Define a regex in a .ini configuration file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way in Python 3 to define a regular expression in a .ini file,
to get a flexible matching criteria within the code?

What I'm trying to achieve, is to be able to match on different output patterns from a subprocess,
and what this matching dynamic, by getting the matching criteria from the .ini file.

Have tried:

```
[DALLAS]
trigger_reg_exp = "r'(.*)JCAT Lightning logs directory:(.*)'"

if re.match(self.dallas_trigger_reg_exp, line):
```

Comment: It will work if you remove the extra delimiters, they shouldn't be part of the regex: `"r' '"`

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting an error? Wrong output?

Answer (score 0):

Like @CherryDT mentioned. You should adjust your regex.
I don´t know your source-text-file, so I can´t test the code if your regex is correct.

##### config.ini

```
[DALLAS]
trigger_reg_exp = (.*)JCAT Lightning logs directory:(.*)
```

##### .py

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import re

cfg = ConfigParser()
cfg.read('config.ini')

print(cfg.get('DALLAS', 'trigger_reg_exp'))

with open('file') as f:
    line = [line for line in f.readline() if re.match(cfg.get('DALLAS', 'trigger_reg_exp'), line)]
```

If you would like to run your `re.match()` on a output of a subprocess you can try that.

```
import shlex
import subprocess 

linux_command = "proc arg1 arg2"

with subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(linux_command)) as proc:
    if re.match(cfg.get('DALLAS', 'trigger_reg_exp'), proc.stdout.read()):
        print("bingo")
```

Here you can find a library of [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-contents) and [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)